# CucumberJS, Protractor, and Angular 5 mock out services

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber, angular-services

I am trying to make some cucumber test cases using protractor with my angular 5 application. I am not sure how to mock my services. I want my components to use my mock service whenever they call functions from them.

Here's a simple example:

foobar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../../../services/test.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    myDataObject: any;

    constructor(private testService: TestService) {
        this.myDataObject = this.testService.getTestObject();
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    constructor() {}

    getTestObject(): any {
        return {
            'foo': 1,
            'bar': 2
        }
    }
}
```

foobar.step.ts

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
const { Before, Given, When, Then, defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber');
const chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
const expect = chai.expect;

defineSupportCode(function ({ setDefaultTimeout }) {
    setDefaultTimeout(120 * 1000);
});

Before(() => {
    // Setup a mock service and use the values I set here. In this case I would want to mock out whatever TestService.getTestObject() returns and have my component use the mock values.
}

Given('some test here', (next) => {
    next();
});

When('the page loads', (next) => {
    browser.get('/').then(function () {
        next();
    });
});

Then('some text here', (next) => {
    // Use mock values and create expect statement to see if something was shown on the page.
});
```

The reason I want to do this is because my templates depend on the values from the objects my services return to determine if some `div` blocks should be shown or not.

How can I mock my service and have my component use it in my protractor tests? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: These are end-to-end tests, outside the Angular application lifecycle, so you can't mock out part of the app. That would be for unit and integration tests, using the Angular TestBed to hook into DI.

Comment: So if I had a feature file like this: https://gist.github.com/MSaIim/08dba26eb546df1b0c01aae0f08ebcbd I wouldn't be able to do it? Assuming the colors are coming from the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments you don't use TestBed for mocking Services in E2E-tests, but you can switch the environments when running tests, thus providing complete mock services:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AbstractService,
      useClass: (environment.mockService ? TestService : RealService) // both extend AbstractService
    }
  ],
  declarations: ...,
  exports: ...
})
export class MyModule {}
```

and in package.json (you need to set the environment with an own file and wire it up in the angular-cli.json as well)...

```
"test": "ng test --env=unit-test",
```

Comment: Can you explain the package.json and angular-cli part? Not sure how the `environment` is being set.

Comment: In your `environment.ts` write `mockService: false` and in your `environment.prod.ts` write `mockService: false`. This way you use the mock only in development and not in production. Or if you want to develop with the real backend and only test with the mock, make another file `environment.unit-test.ts` and set mockService to true only there. Also put `name: "unit-test"` in that file. Then go to `angular-cli.json` and declare `"environments": {"dev": "environments/environment.ts","unit-test": "environments/environment.unit-test.ts","prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"}`

Comment: now you have created a new environment specifcally for unit-tests

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get a service a component is using in the cucumber file? For example, with Jasmine tests, I can use the `TestBed` and `inject` to get a component or service.

Comment: @o.o We don't use cucumber; we just write inline comments given-when-then for BDD. The official Angular team doesn't support cucumber (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20145) and the tutorials on the internet are sparse, I am afraid. I recommend to open a separate question about accessing injected services in unit tests. This question here is about e2e-tests and there you don't access services. You navigate over the interface and you check what the interface produces. All the services are blackboxes.